# Определение страницы и подгрузка контента

Tags: php, mysql

Прощу откликнуться проффесионалов PHP. Как лучше реализовать определение запроса и подгрузки контента. У меня сейчас это всё работает следующим образом.

Шаблон:

```
<?php
    include('classes/content.php');
    if(!isset($_GET['show'])){
        $show = 'main';
    }
    else {
        $show = addslashes(strip_tags(trim($_GET['show'])));
    }
    $data = new Content;
    $result = $data->get_content($show);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?=$result["title"]?></title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="icons/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
        <link href="http://yandex.st/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="panel panel-default islogged">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="admin_menu">
                    <a href="/">Главная</a>
                    <a href="/edit">Редактирование</a>
                    <a href="/?logout" style="color: red">Выход</a>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <?=$result["text"]?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Класс:

```
<?php
    class Content {
        public $connection = null;

        public function get_content ($show) {
            //Connection
            $this->connection = new mysqli(host,login,password,name);
            $this->connection->set_charset('utf8');
            //Check connection
            if(!$this->connection->connect_errno) {
                //Check page
                $query = $this->connection->query("SELECT title, text FROM content WHERE name = '$show'");
                //Check exist page
                if($query->num_rows == 1) {
                    return $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                }
                else {
                    return array(
                        "title" => "Ошибка",
                        "text" => "Такой страницы не существует",
                    );
                }
            }
            else {
                return array(
                    "title" => "Ошибка",
                    "text" => "Ошибка подключения к базе",
                );
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

перенеси в класс проверку get:

```
public $render;

public function __construct()
{

    if(!isset($_GET['show'])){
        $show = 'main';
    }
    else {
        $show = addslashes(strip_tags(trim($_GET['show'])));
    }

    $data = $this->get_content ($show);
    $this->render =  (object) $data;
}
```

Вывод:

```
$content = new Content;
$content->render->title;
$content->render->text;
```

Comment: Контент не должен проверять, что там валяется в данный момент в окружении (которое, к тому же, легко меняется). Его единственная задача - вывод непосредственно контента с тем ключом, который ему указали, сам он его выдумывать не должен.

Comment: А можно возвращаемые данные в массив засунуть? Ну то есть чтобы не создавать кучу переменных public а в массив все это?

Comment: сделай отдельную функцию и возвращай ей то, что нужно. а паблики перенести в приват или вообще переменную типа array сделать и в нее пихать из разных необходимых функций и возвращать уже готовый массив.

Comment: можно сделать одну перменную public (public $render;)
в нее записывать $this->render = (object) $data;
вывод будет следующим: 
$content = new Content; 
$content->render->title;